# Dual boot Linux Mint 17.1 with OS X Lion

Tags: macos, startup, unix

I have a 13' MacBook (2007, hw.model: 2,1) running OS X Lion (10.7). I wish to dual-boot Linux Mint 17.1 alongside OS X.  I created a Partition for Linux, and have also installed rEFIt (0.14). I have created a LiveUSB as well as the Live DVD for installing Linux Mint.

When I use the LiveUSB and select Linux option in rEFIt, I get the following error:

```
Starting legacy loader
Using load option 'USB'
Error: Not Found returned from legacy loader
Error: Not Found returned from LocateDevicePath
Error: Not Found returned from LocateDevicePath
Error: Not Found returned from LocateDevicePath
Error: Not Found returned from LocateDevicePath
Error: Not Found returned from LocateDevicePath
Error: Not Found returned from LocateDevicePath
Error: Not Found returned from LocateDevicePath
Error: Not Found returned from LocateDevicePath
Error: Not Found returned from LocateDevicePath
Error: Not Found returned from LocateDevicePath
Error: Not Found returned from LocateDevicePath
Error: Not Found returned from LocateDevicePath
Error: Load Error while (re)opening our installation volume

The firmware refused to boot from the selected volume. Note that external
hard drives are not well-supported by Apple's firmware for legacy OS booting.

* Hit any key to continue *
```

And when I use the LiveDVD (with and without holding down 'c'), the disk just gets ejected. I burnt 2 new DVDs, and also tested installing it on another machine, where it installed successfully.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this are welcome.

Comment: Support for rEFIt has been dropped. You may have better luck with [rEFInd](http://rodsbooks.com/refind/)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same hardware and experienced the same problem. Booting from DVD and USB didn't work so I created a new partition on the hard drive, copied the Linux iso onto it and booted off that.  Got it installed ok but the fans were running all the time so I gave up on it in the end.